# How does my society manage to not fall apart?

Tags: society, culture, fantasy-races, immortality

So, I am writing a story which is set in a world almost identical to real, except there is small difference, about ten percent of human population ages almost twice as fast as normal, they reach "biological 50s" in 30s, but still have average lifespan. And another ten percent doesn't age after 20 until death (they live same as average life expectancy of their population, science behind this is irrelevant and handwaved). Non-agers are also immune to aging related diseases, they will have same look, energy level, creativity, agility, sex drive, brain plasticity at 50 as normal 20 year old.

Story is set in pre world war era, technologically. Which means people can't use genetic engeneering and plastical surgery is very basic.

- What advantages can fast-agers have in this unfair setting ?

Comment: I think that it will tear itself apart. 10% of your society don't age, and 10% age faster, at least in appearance. Everybody, especially the fast-agers, want what the slow-agers have.

Comment: @NomadMaker Interesting, could you answer this question, ie how would it fall ?

Comment: Hello Terry. Welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. When you have a moment, please take our [tour] and review our [help]. It's important to realize that Stack Exchange is not a discussion forum, but a Q&A site. The model is one-specific-question/one-best-answer. One of the vote-to-close reasons is that there's more than one question being asked. Another is that the question isn't specific enough. Q#1 is off-topic because we'll help you design your world, but we won't design it for you. Q#2 is too broad and opinion-based. Q#3 is too story-based (it can be anything you want).

Comment: @JBH Thank you for your input, edited the question.

Comment: Just one question, please. You've updated your list. Q#3 is now entirely not about worldbuilding (another vote-to-close reason). Remember... one *specific* problem. Q#2 comes closest to that, but considering humanity as it is has experienced every conceivable political structure, I can't imagine why your world wouldn't experience the same. The unusual aging issues don't affect government (they would affect the medical industry).

Comment: OK, one more effort then I need to move on to other things. Your question(s) are so broad that you're asking us to write your story for you. Your first bullet has two nearly unrelated questions in it. The second bullet (optional or not) is a question better asked in your town's local writer's group. The question is going to get closed. Stack Exchange is designed for you to select a single, best answer. How will you judge the answers based on the non-specificity of your questions? Please remember, ***one specific question.***

Comment: What kind of hard science do you expect people to provide? I could think of some scientific studies that would help with building social frameworks in your world, but I cannot really think about anything that would be directly useful for your question. Also, questions in the title and the body are worlds apart. Which one do you want to be answered?

Comment: Thanks, Terry. I've retracted my close vote. Please be aware that the [tag:hard-science] tag is ruthless. It requires respondents to back up their answers with mathematics, published analyses and articles, etc. Answers that don't meet its mandate can be deleted. You might want to read through its wiki and be sure that's a tag you need.

Comment: I thought hard science meant just realistic answer, not backups and sources @JBH

Comment: @TerryGlebnerr Nope... It's ruthless. Only use it if you really mean it. [tag:science-based] is what you use for "realistic." Remember, we're all developing fictional worlds, so there's a bit of tongue-in-cheek here. What you want is suspension-of-disbelief. [tag:hard-science] is when you story absolutely depends on scientific proof.

Answer (score 2):

Frame shift. I believe that this people will tear most real-world societies apart.

You have two groups which are visibly different from human norms that I believe that would be hated by the "normal" people.

The slow-agers would be seen as somehow blessed, either by higher or lower powers. Either they are blessed by the Divinity or using power of the Enemy.

The fast-agers will be seen as cursed.

In normal human society people that are seen as different are treated poorly. I believe that in this society the normals will treat both small groups badly. Eventually both groups will get tired of this treatment and fight back. There will be fighting and riots.

The normal and fast agers will *want* what the slow-agers have. The slow-agers can't give it to them. People will be killed over this.

Comment: This is a very unlikely scenario. All societies reach equilibrium in one way or another. Constant infighting is not sustainable. Slow ageing is not something that can be removed by force and given to other people. It is a genetic effect per OP. Do we fight pretty people in our world? Did we ever fight pretty people as a class of people?

Comment: @Otkin The extent of Nomad's answer is questionable, but not his premise. Children are mean to the point of ruthless toward peers that are perceived as ugly, fat, retarded, socially inept, or any other mean-spirited description you care to provide. Adults are, too, we're just more subtle about it, but at least a few would grow up to pity the over-agers (but wouldn't prefer to socialize with them). On the other end of the spectrum is the Cult of Celebrity that isn't recognizable until adulthood that would follow the under-agers. I've counseled too many people to believe otherwise.

Comment: @JBH I agree that discrimination can be based on even the subtlest differences. I also agree that children can be very mean. But even the most intolerant societies do not tear themselves apart. They build caste systems, they legalise and enshrine discrimination, they create marginalised groups or untouchables, and so on. The final result is more or less stable and can exist for thousands of years. Here we are talking about biological differences (I assume they existed as long as anyone can tell). We may want not to age. But there is nothing we can do about it if we do not have the genes.

Comment: @Otkin Infighting doesn't have to be in form visible violence. It's often subtle and institutionalized.

Comment: @TerryGlebnerr This answer states that there will be fighting and riots, that people will be killed over this. I can imagine isolated episodes of fighting, riots, and killings. But it is highly unlikely that something like this will be a norm. Again, that would not be sustainable. What you are talking about is discrimination, which is different from NomadMaker's open violence. I would write you a proper answer, but you need to fix your question first and answer my comment on your original post.

Answer (score 2):

**We live in this world.**

Many of the Founding Fathers lived into their 80s and 90s.  They were slow agers.  This in large part because they lived sheltered lives of affluence.  They had good food starting in childhood.  They did not have to do manual labor.

Persons with hard lives and meager resources age fast.  Work uses them up.  Joints and muscles used hard every day wear down faster.  Poor nutrition takes its toll.  Old injuries accumulate.  You can really see this with men in their 60s.  Some men at 65 are well into decline, cognitively and physically.  Some men at 65 look like they stopped aging at 40 and will likely stay that way until cancer claims them at 90.

Your fast ageing protagonist is happy to be on the right side of the ground.  He cannot drive it like he stole it, and in fact those days were over for him so soon they did not leave much of a mark.  Old injuries that are not that old slow him down and limit what he does.  He must use reading glasses.  He has to play it like an old guy - scheming and canny.  Not a young guy counting on strength and reflexes.

The perennially young are like young people have always been.  They feel good and they may or may not take their physical blessings for granted.  They think fast and move fast and they can be impulsive, because their physical being does not compel them to take more time - time which can also be used for consideration.

People can dream of things being better, but the expectation that something better is coming or is due might be a particularly American thing.  Probably more often people content themselves with what they have and seek to avoid loss, rather than gamble what they have for uncertain gain.

This could be a fine high-concept science fiction.  In a manner somewhat like Gattaca, you could leverage the standpoint of these aging differences and use it as a vantage point to comment on class and economic differences in the real world.

Comment: This is both right and wrong.  Right in that we have people aging at different rates, wrong about the cause.  It is not the "hard labor" that wears you out before your time, it's smoking, eating (especially typical western "fast food" diets) & drinking to excess, and NOT getting enough exercise.

Answer (score 2):

I will answer pre-edit questions as well.

Your MC can survive but their life will be bleak and miserable, age related health decline and discrimination is as bad and brutal as it can get for normal people, now add another layer to it. Fast agers will be extremely discriminated against. They will be seen as burden and liability, by commoners and non agers, they also will be heavily exploited, and be indirectly forced into low wage dead end physical labour which ironically will wear them even faster,  because of their short *useful* lifespans they will have extremely small time to build up power, status or finances.

On contrary to the other answers however there won't be any rebelion or class war. There is lot of successful activism and protesting against racism, sexism, classism, animal welfare, ecology, dictatorship and other unfairness around the world. But not about that much about ageism. Why ?

- It is hard to go to protest and weave the flag, when walking two miles is challenge and your joints fail. Less elderly go to protests, thus less of their problems are considered.
- It is hard to get someone listen to you and maintain sound social circle when you no longer work or are in education. How many friends do you have now ? How many you will have in 20 years ? What will be your social footprint at 70 ?
- It is hard to pry away spotlight from younger, louder, vibrant, livelier, better looking peers. How many 60+ are you following on IG/FB/Youtube. If you are 30+ what are chances someone wants to see your face on tiktok ?

Non-agers will be uncontested rulers. They will have social skills of wise politician, one that normally comes in autumn years, yet retain powerful, attractive bodies that masses look up to,  they retain energy and prowess of peak human. They have youthful confidence backed up by wisdom. They will be basically worshiped as gods.

Your MC will go through brutalities and hardships of life wothout silver lining, without light at the end of dark tunnel.

Answer (score 1):

This I think would depend on the larger context of how you did set your world.

Civil wars exist and they have their actual reasons and background. But also we had slavery then it was abolished and step by step humans are largely equal nowadays in most countries and besides corruption everything is equal in the eyes of the law.

Now I will get to non law discrimination but for now let's focus on the larger aspect of the 3 groups.

First you **have** to tell us about the passing of genes in the 2 extreme groups. I think this is vital because of a fast ager and non ager had a child then what that child is? Non ager and a normal person or 2 non agers and so on. This would change a lot and here is an example.

A fast ager born to a wealthy family will easily find a non ager wife that is **not** doing well financially. So will that "fix" the children?
But also he can just find her on his own, not everything is about money.

Anyway here are **major** points about the actual world and success.

- Money.
- Intelligence.

**Money**

I don't care how good looking you are. If you are a billionaire then the whole world opens up to you. This is just the world. We are no longer dependent on strength of arms and humans do look for beauty, but man wealth is better.

Also if you are rich then you can just buy strength of arms, but not the other way around.

So the idea that an aging/non aging is a problem is true. But so is wealth/poverty.

So, like before, a faster ager or non ager or "normal" persons place in society won't just depend on that.

In everything from choosing a partner to influencing elections, using the media at least, money is the biggest factor.

**Intelligence**

Obviously youth is great and you are more creative at a young age with more energy.
But intelligence is such a huge tool that it breaks the game.
Intelligence can be unaffected by age or body. You can have a fast ager with the intelligence of Tesla and have them be in their 70s for that matters.

This also translate into other fields. A fast ager programmer can easily make millions if they are smart enough and thus elevate themselves into the category of fast ager but with money thus getting into my previous points.

So basically I think that human society will work mostly be the same

Here are further points:

An average non ager would do better, but not much better.

Actual hard labor gets you little money and offers little future. That is why our society is more into stuff that has a future and a career path. So yes being in your 40 with the body of a 20 years old is great. This is not an extreme sports, more on that, so even a 40 year old normal person can still do the job fine.

Most jobs focus on experience and knowledge and the only way to actually gain that is by doing it, being smart helps, so age is mostly meaningless here.

Sports is where things will be different. The non agers would probably dominate but, again, talent and experience will still play a rule.

I can mention 35-40 old keepers who still play football, actual football, with the best clubs and still some of the best in the world.
This despite having goalkeepers 20 years younger in the game.

Why? Again it falls into the category of talent and experience. Even in sports.

No exploitable.

You also can't do anything to either group. The fast agers and non agers are not cheap labor. They are not slaves bought from another country. They are not a minority or religious group. So from what I understand it just appears in people randomly and could be any group.

Actual discrimination tends to be directed towards certain groups with ethnic or similar backgrounds. Assume group A is of another ethnic group and have their own language and culture but small numbers and live in their own state. Now assume the country is a dictatorship. Well. those people can be bullied like crazy because they are a small group with different overall culture from the norm.
Actual dictatorships also prefer to sow dissent.

However those people, in your world, just appear.

They also offer nothing more in the way of exploitation or anything.

Lets look at immigrant workers going to a 1st world country.

They can be abused as many of them don't have paper work, they also need the work, they have no one too look out for them, they are also accustomed to hard work and oppression, and lastly they would accept whatever meager wages a corrupt employer offers.

But a citizen with knowledge of the law and rights and being born into the culture is less likely to be exploited in this manner. Yes exploitation is not just for certain groups but I'm saying less likely.

So from a business or governmental stand point is pretty much meaningless to discriminate.

Even in the military officers, especially higher ups, are chosen for intelligence more than anything.

Moltke, Rommel, Napoleon, Clausewitz...etc could be quadriplegic midgets with
a 100 health conditions and they will still be some of the greatest generals and military minds in history.
The example is a bit humorous, or attempted humor, because in reality your parameters would still allow them to be generals.

So at best the fast agers will just have to show military abilities to lead from a young age or will get a different military path where they can be officers and higher ups.

This is important as the military actually wants **everyone** they can get their hands on. This is mostly in empires like Rome or modern states, think France or the USSR, and they still want the intelligent agers as officers.

I know other contexts are different like medieval Europe and knights.

This is pretty much the exact same in everything and every career path.

You can also see this at play with other things but that might get too political.

**TL:DR humans discriminate with a lot of things but the biggest two factors for most things are money and intelligence.
Choosing a partner adds the elements of beauty and character. But I digress.

In your world things won't change much.**

Comment: Being old is not just about body, but also brain, active time and energy, I learned english to near fluency by the time i turned 15, my younger peers learned it way faster while my friend started at 30 and is still learning, now we are in mid 40s. When I was young i needed less sleep, had more free time per day and more energy to make use of that time.

Comment: @HiroshiAKIYAMA,
Far more complex than just that.
I mentioned the keeper example to show that even pure reaction time is NOT the only thing. Even at the top tier sports level.
You also have to account to a lot of thing such as: diet, genetics, intelligence, experience...etc.
A60you wrestler constantly working out can beat the crap out of a 20 yo despite his youth. 
I also said that in most things experience and knowledge is better.
Maybe in an FPS a younger person can do better. But in the real world it is not as simple. as youth is magic.
Even in language smarter=easier learning.

Answer (score 0):

#### How does your society manage to not fall apart?

You society has 3 different levels of privilege, a blessed class (live for ever at 20), a common class, and a cursed class (those who age real quickly). An upper class, a middle class, and a lower class.

Pre-world war 2, societies had ways of taking differing levels of privilege and keeping society together: Legalised discrimination. In America it was called [Jim Crow Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jim_Crow_laws), in Australia we legally classed our Aboriginal People as fauna. Etc. I'd expect your society to take 1930's racism, sexism, traditional ageism, and add age-rate-ism to that list.

Your classes will be separated from as soon as they enter school - your "fasts" (quick agers) are too big to sit with students at their own level, and too dumb to be taught with those their own size. They'll struggle to make friends except with other fasts. They'll be undereducated compared to their peers.

Given the 1930's eugenics interest, the lower class may of been targeted for removal from the gene pool by radical groups. Hitler would probably include them in his concentration camp round ups.

Rounding up people and putting them in concentration camps is what I'd define as falling apart, but your world is doing no worse than the control.

#### Other observations (You asked for these in one edit):

- All age based laws in your society are a lot trickier to enforce. You have people who look like adults who have the mind of a pre-teen. You have elderly who look like young adults. You have people drinking in bars who look too young, you have seniors who look decrepit but can still legally drive, you have adults who are still in primary school.
- Age of consent laws. Two 30-year-old-looking people can hook up in a bar, one gets charged with statutory rape because the other was only 15.
- Blessed people can't be academics, CEOs, Doctors, Priests, etc - no-one takes the word of a 20-something seriously on complex issues, they look like a student, not a researcher.

#### How does your main character (a Fastie) survive?

Same way other discriminate people have survived through this and other periods of discrimination: Be useful. If your motivated and hard working and keep your head down you'll survive this era.

Also, get out of Europe ASAP. Bad stuff is about to happen there. Don't go to Asia, northern Africa, northern Australia, or Russia.

Comment: Solid answer, ops world is order of magnitude more brutal than anything by Orwell.

Comment: Non-ageing people do not live forever. They just do not age and do not have senile disorders. Who are fasts? Not ageing does not make one faster or smarter. I also think that in a society like OP describes appearance will not be seen as an indicator of age as we use it in our world. We perceive younger-looking people as inexperienced because we age at almost the same pace. If we had a lot of people who do not age (and 10% is a lot), we would not equate youth with inexperience.